# Writing to public google folder and google sheets withouth the use of oauth2?

Tags: python-3.x, api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

is it possible to use the google drive api for writing data into public google folders / sheets without an oauth2 token but rather just with the api-key of my application? I found something [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#APIKey) but could not integrate into our existing python script where I used the [oauth-method](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) so far.

The need for moving away from oauth2 to the api key arises since we would like to easily share our application without sharing the token and without having our users to authorize our application since we only intend to write to public google folders / sheets anyway.

Cheers!

Comment: Although API key can use GET method, POST and PUT methods cannot be used by the API key. So for example, how about using [Web Apps of Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)? After the Web Apps was deployed, users can access to the Web Apps using request without access token. The write and read Spreadsheet can be set by GAS, and users can also give the parameters as the query parameters. If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your input. While this is an option indeed, we still prefer to not have to deploy and maintain any web app, but just share a simple python script which so far perfectly fulfills our needs, except for the problem with authentication and oauth2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research, there doesn't seem to be an option of using Google's Drive and Sheets API without the usage of oauth2 credentials.

So, when we share our application, the user would need to manually create a client_secret.json from the google developer console and then obatin a credentials.json

Unfortunately. But well, that's how it is. Most importantly is this tutorial for our scenario: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python